# Error for invalid floating-point numbers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, floating-point, precision

Quoting from Learning SQL 3rd edition by Alan Beaulieu:
"A float(4,2) column would handle the numbers 27.44 and 8.19 just fine, but the number 17.8675 would be rounded to 17.87, and attempting to store the number 178.375 in your float(4,2) column would generate an error."

Why does this approximation happen for the first example and not for the latter? Why isn't 178.375 approximated to 178.4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the difference between precision and scale.  A `float(4, 2)` has four digits of precision and a scale of 2.  The scale is numbers to the *right* of the decimal place.  So there are `4 - 2 = 2` places to the *left*.  (It is a coincidence that there are two positions to the left and right in this case.)

The value 178. has three values to the left.  There are not enough positions for them.  Hence the error.

I should note that `float(p, s)` is rather specific to MySQL and I strongly, strongly discourage using it.  Instead, use the standard data type for fixed length numbers, which is called `numeric`/`decimal`.  So, use `decimal(4, 2)`.

Comment: So a scale of 2 means that 2 numbers to the right of the decimal are mandatory and not just maximum permited right? That's why 178.4 wouldn't be permitted?

Comment: @ȘtefanTeodor . . . Yes, that is the idea.  I mean "mandatory" is not quite the right word.  It basically says that of the four place, two are reserved to the right of the decimal place.